# use replica to store capped collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, capped-collections

Is it possible to create a capped collection in a read only mode at a single replica in MongoDB? There is a main database with replica set and I need to use a capped collection with a AWS queue to listen for new insertions. In order to avoid possible listening overloads in the main database, I was wonder whether is possible to create a capped in one of the replicas.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as at now. Also keep in mind that replication's main purpose it to have similar data through out the replica set.

Comment: thank you @PSJ
I thought this would be the case however I notice you can create capped collections in the main database without propagate it through the replica set. So it's worth asking with the contrary could be possible